# Filter tweets with hashtag from specific user

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I want to filter the Tweets from a specific user which have a specific #hashtag. I'm using the Tweepy package and Python.

Here is my code:

```
tt=tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,
      q='#eko_kendimenotlar',
      id=42209639,
      page=1,
      count=10,
      tweet_mode='extended').items()

for i in tt:
    print(i.full_text)
```

But I get all the Tweets from the user rather than ones filtered by hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

The [`API.user_timeline` method](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline) / [GET statuses/user_timeline endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) doesn't accept a `q` parameter.

You'll have to filter them yourself. You could just check for the hashtag in the text of each Tweet.

Another way to do this would be to use the `entities` attribute of [Tweet objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object), which are [entities objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object) containing `hashtags` fields that are arrays of [hashtag objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object#hashtags) representing hashtags which have been parsed from the Tweet text.

Alternatively, you could use [`API.search`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.search) / [the standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) and the `from:` [standard search operator](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators).